# Error while trying to store pig output to the Hive Table

Tags: hadoop

**I created the Hive Table under database testdb:**

create table tbl2 (year string, DeptTime string, ArrTime string) stored as ORC;

**after that i created the following Pig Script:**

A = LOAD '/test/input/' USING PigStorage(',') AS (year:chararray,ArrTime:chararray,DeptTime:chararray);

describe A;

dump A;

**while executing the above script it works fine.**

**But adding following line to store pig output to hive it will throw an error.**

A = LOAD '/test/input/' USING PigStorage(',') AS (year:chararray,ArrTime:chararray,DeptTime:chararray);

describe A;

dump A;

store A into 'testdb.tbl2' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();

**used PIG Argument -useHCatalog**

**Error:**

ls: cannot access '/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/admin/appcache/application_1493274253049_0026/container_1493274253049_0026_01_000002/hive.tar.gz/hive/lib/slf4j-api-*.jar': No such file or directory ls: cannot access '/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/admin/appcache/application_1493274253049_0026/container_1493274253049_0026_01_000002/hive.tar.gz/hive/hcatalog/lib/*hbase-storage-handler-*.jar':

Answer (score 0):

Have you started hive thrift server? If not, use below command and then check

**hive --service metatore**

Comment: I am using HDInsight cluster on azure. si how can i check hive thrift server has started or not ?

i am new to hadoop world.